# Extend theorem header with title by citation

Tags: citing, theorems, ntheorem

How can I redefine the theorem style, so that I can provide two "optional" arguments (I'm fine with using `\begin{Definition}[title]{}` if no citation is wanted.)

I **guess** I'm quite flexible with the used package, right now I use `\listtheorems{Definition}` from `ntheorem`, but I'm unsure, if I want to keep this.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[amsthm,thmmarks,hyperref]{ntheorem}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{Definition}{Definition}[section]

\begin{document}
\begin{Definition}[title]
content
\end{Definition}

%goal:
\noindent\textbf{Definition 0.1 (title) \cite{testA}.} content

\cite{testA} %should not be bold here, so redefining \@cite wouldn't work?!

\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\bibitem{testA} Author A. Title A. 2019
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I think what you want can be solved by using just one optional argument -- but you need to use braces around the cite to "hide" the extra square brackets from latex if you have a complex citation: `\begin{Definition}[title {\cite[Theorem~2]{testA}}]`.  With `amsthm` the title and citation will be in normal weight, not bold.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the argument pattern syntax of `\def` to split the optional argument in two using a separator character. This is conceptually not very clean (it would be better to actually use a second optional argument) and has practical issues (you can't use the separator character in the title or in the cite key) but it may be sufficient for the intended application.

In the MWE below the command `\thcite` is defined that takes as argument a `|`, some characters, another `|`, some characters, and another `|`. In the definition of the new theorem style there is a test (using `\IfSubStr` from the `xstring` package) to see if there is a `|` in the optional argument. If so, the `\thcite` command is used (adding `|` characters at the start and end of the argument), if not then the argument is just repeated between parentheses. A Definition without optional argument is handled by the first part of the new theorem style which just prints the label name and number in bold.

If you want to use `\listtheorems` then the easiest solution is to use starred theorems (which do not appear in the list) for titles with a reference, and to add a separate line to the list with the correctly formatted list entry.

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=black]{hyperref}
\usepackage[amsthm,thmmarks,hyperref]{ntheorem}
\usepackage{xstring}

% addtheoremline for use with \listtheorems
\def\thcite|#1|#2|{(#1) \cite{#2}\addtheoremline{citedef}{#1 \cite{#2}}}

\makeatletter
\newtheoremstyle{citedef}%
{\item[\normalfont\bfseries \hskip\labelsep ##1 ##2\theorem@separator]\normalfont}%
{\item[\normalfont\bfseries \hskip\labelsep ##1 ##2 \IfSubStr{##3}{|}{\thcite|##3|}{(##3)}.\theorem@separator]\normalfont}%
\makeatother

\theoremstyle{citedef}

\newtheorem{citedef}{Definition}[section]

\begin{document}
\begin{citedef}
content
\end{citedef}

\begin{citedef}[title]
content
\end{citedef}

% starred environment for use with \listtheorems
\begin{citedef*}[title|testA]
content
\end{citedef*}

\cite{testA} %should not be bold here

\listtheorems{citedef}

\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\bibitem{testA} Author A. Title A. 2019
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Is it also possible to make `\listtheorems{citedef}` work properly, i. e. instead of `0.3 title---testA` either print only `0.3 title` or `0.3 title [1]`

Comment: @Ben It's possible with a custom `\addtheoremline`, see edit.

Comment: This doesn't work properly, if I also want to use `citetheo`

Comment: Maybe the counters need some extra processing in that case - but it would probably be better to ask that in a new question with a new MWE.

Comment: I think, you could improve your answer by choosing different names for the `theoremstyle` and `theorem`

Comment: Can this also be adapted for theorems with a citation, but without a title `\begin{citedef*}[|testA]`?

Comment: I achieved this by `\def\thcite|#1|#2|{\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}{}{(#1) }\cite{#2}}`